# How bad is to use void pointer in std::vector declaration?

Tags: c++, vector, void

I have two different classes as below:

```
class text
{ };

class element
{ };
```

And I want to store them in the `class node`:

```
template <typename T>
class node
{
    T cargo;

    std::vector<void*> children;

    node(T cargo) : cargo(cargo)
    { };

    void add_child(T node)
    {
        this->children.push_back((void*) node);
    }
}
```

So I would call the node this way storing both, `text` and `element`'s:

```
element div;
text msg;

node<element> wrapper(div);

wrapper.add_child(msg);
```

**EDIT**: To get back the content I use `T typedef type;` and convert void pointer to `(type*)`.

I know that's not very elegant nor functional, but I just can't figure out what's the correct way of doing that. So please tell me if this is practically acceptable and if it is not, how to do that in the proper manner.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How about, y'know... a base class?

Comment: Note above: unless T is a primitive or pointer type, it's unlikely that it will fit into the size of a void*.  You might want: add_child(T* node) ... push_back((void*)node); instead.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class Element {};
class Text {};
class Nothing {};

class Node
{
private:
    vector< Node* >     children_;
protected:
    Node() {}
public:
    void add( Node* p ) { children_.push_back( p ); }
    virtual ~Node() {}
};

template< class Cargo >
class CargoNode
    : public Node
{
private:
    Cargo   cargo_;
public:
    CargoNode(): cargo_() {}
};

typedef CargoNode< Element >    ElementNode;
typedef CargoNode< Text >       TextNode;
typedef CargoNode< Nothing >    RootNode;

int main()
{
    RootNode*   root    = new RootNode;

    root->add( new ElementNode );
    root->add( new ElementNode );
    root->add( new TextNode );
    root->add( new ElementNode );   
    // Etc.
}
```

Cheers & hth.,

PS: Error checking, lifetime management, iteration etc. omitted in this example code.

Comment: Nice solution. Hadn't considered type erasure.

Comment: @Kas: I think you mean "polymorphism" :-) At least the way my association circuits currently resolve the terms, `boost::any` is an example of type erasure. You have a known narrow interface to something, and behind that you tuck an object of almost any type, sort of hardwiring in the glue via some templating (generating code that does a bit of casting). Cheers,

Comment: This is cleaner and easier to use then all other proposals! Thank you.

Comment: @Alf: You're right, it's not quite type erasure (because the interfaces between Node and T aren't the same), but I still like it because you've not had to create a false relationship between text and element and whatever else.  The dynamic_cast<>ing necessary to get the information back out again might be a bit painful, though.  Not that switch(ch.type) is better...

Comment: @Kaz Dragon: Is the `dynamic_cast<>ing` the only way to get information back in this case?

Comment: @Rizo: Since all the objects are stored as base Node*s, then some kind of lookup will be required to convert them to the correct CargoNode<> in order to retrieve their cargo.  I do it below by carrying a type around, this does it by using a class heirarchy.  They're two different solutions for the same problem.

Answer (score 5):

I would say that void* is nearly always "bad" (for some definition of bad).  Certainly, there are likely to be better ways of expressing what it is you're trying to do.  If it were me writing this code and I knew the types of the values I was going to put in, then I would consider using a [Boost.Variant](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/doc/html/variant.html).  If I didn't (for example, this was supplied as a library to someone else to "fill up"), then I would use [Boost.Any](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/doc/html/any.html)

For example:

```
template <class T, class U>
struct node
{
    typedef boost::variant<T, U> child_type;

    std::vector<child_type> children;

    void add_child(T const &t)
    {
        children.push_back(t);
    }

    void add_child(U const &u)
    {
        children.push_back(u);
    }
};

...

node<text, element> n;
n.add_child(text("foo"));
```

A non-boost typed union solution:

```
struct node
{
    struct child
    {
        int type; // 0 = text; 1 = element

        union 
        {
            text*    t;
            element* e;
        } u;
    };

    std::vector<child> children;

    void add_child(text* t)
    {
        child ch;
        ch.type = 0;
        ch.u.t  = t;

        children.push_back(ch);
    }

    void add_child(element* e)
    {
        child ch;
        ch.type = 1;
        ch.u.e  = t;

        children.push_back(ch);
    }
};
```

Note: you have to be a whole lot more careful about memory management with the typed union.

Comment: I don't use boost. But the union solution that boost::variant uses seems to be interesting. Is there any minimalistic implementation of it?
Thank you.

Comment: @Rizo: I'm not sure what you mean by "minimalistic"; could you elaborate?  Anyway, I updated my answer to be more in line with what you were asking in the question.

Comment: I asked for a possible 'simple' alternative of boost::variant, since I can't use boost.

Comment: @Rizo Why can't you use boost? If this is homework then I would assume that you misunderstood the assignment. If this is normal work or your personal project, then I don't understand why would not be able to use boost.

Comment: @Rizo: Well, base class or void* are the other ways, or I guess a typed union: struct child { int type; union { text* t; element* e } u; }; vector<node_content> children;

Answer (score 1):

How would you get them back if you do this? From a `void*` there is no way to determine what is actually stored on the address.

Edit:
If you always do a cast into `T*` then you can simply take `T*` as the parameter.

Comment: Yes, but this in turn may be deduced from other parameters, depending on the program logic

Comment: @Rizo You want to store both types or just one? Why are you taking the template parameter then? Please explain further.

Comment: I want to store them both. `node`'s children vector should be able to store `element`s and `text`. My container class is keeping register of the types are being added and then uses them to restore the values.

Comment: @Rizo Then you shouldn't take `T` as a parameter in the `add_child()` method.

Answer (score 1):

Define a shared base class for `element` and `text` and then `add_child` can take a pointer to the base class, and the vector can store pointers to the base class.

Comment: I have to say that, while it might solve the problem, adding faux base classes to unrelated types doesn't feel like a very good solution to me.

Comment: Since they are both capable of being children of nodes I think they are probably related types.

Answer (score 1):

If your container value is limited to a small number of types, you could achieve this using `boost::variant` as shown here:

```
#include <vector>
#include <boost/variant.hpp>

using namespace std;

class text
{ };

class element
{ };

template <typename T>
class node
{
    T cargo;

    static std::vector<boost::variant<text, element>> children;

    node(const T& cargo) : cargo(cargo)
    { };

    void add_child(const T& node)
    {
        children.push_back(boost::variant<text, element>(node));
    }
};
```

I have taken the liberty of suggesting a couple of other mods - use `const` reference instead of pass-by-value on `node` constructor and `add_child`; make the container `children` static as I don't think it makes sense for each `node<T>` to have its own container. Locking would be required for multithreaded usage of `add_child` in this case. These comments apply whether you can use Boost or not in your final solution.

You can perform operations on the `vector` elements using either `get` or `static_visitor` - the latter is preferable since you can make this generic - as shown [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/doc/html/variant/tutorial.html#variant.tutorial.basic). An example of `vector` iteration analogous to what you would use for this solution:

```
class times_two_generic
    : public boost::static_visitor<>
{
public:

    template <typename T>
    void operator()( T & operand ) const
    {
        operand += operand;
        cout << operand << endl;
    }

};

std::vector< boost::variant<int, std::string> > vec;
vec.push_back( 21 );
vec.push_back( "hello " );

times_two_generic visitor;
std::for_each(
      vec.begin(), vec.end()
   , boost::apply_visitor(visitor)
   );
```

Output is:

> 42
>
> hello hello

Answer (score 0):

First, there's no such a thing as "bad" to use a void pointer. Forget all the conventions and bla-blas, and do what's most appropriate for your case.

Now, in you specific case, if there's any connection between those two classes - you may declare a base class, so that those two will inherit it. Then, you may declare the vector of a pointer of that base class.

Comment: Can the `node` be itself the base class for `element` ans `text`? Could you, please, show a quick sample code?